# IE 10 @keyframes

Tags: css, css3, internet-explorer, scss

Не работает то ли animation, то ли keyframes в IE10, как ни пытался все равно побороть не могу вот то, что реализовал уже http://codepen.io/geek_of_cola/pen/XNdBmb. Может есть какие-нибудь идеи, использовал префиксы -ms, но и с ними тоже не работает

```
 svg.line__counter path {
        @include animation-fill-mode(forwards);
        @include animation(dash 4s linear 0s infinite);
    }



@include keyframes(dash, -ms -moz -webkit) {
    100% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: #1ebcd9;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-dashoffset: 467;
        stroke-dasharray: 200 264;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 11 и ниже не поддерживают CSS Transitions для SVG. Можете попробовать [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/).